# BigQuery: How to insert a new value in repeated record?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to save a history of user statuses.

For this I have a table with two colums: user_identifier and status.

user_identifier is a string, status is a repeated record with key:value pairs: date and status.

When a user changes a status (for example from active to inactive), I would like to update this table and add the new status, while keeping the old one.

This is the table schema:

```
[
{
"description": "user identifier",
"mode": "REQUIRED",
"name": "user_id",
"type": "STRING"
},
{
"description": "status - can be either sent or pending, initial state is pending",
"mode": "REPEATED",
"name": "status",
"type": "RECORD",
"fields": [
  {
  "name": "status_date",
  "type": "DATE",
  "mode": "REQUIRED"
  },
  {
  "name": "value",
  "type": "STRING",
  "mode": "REQUIRED"
  }
]
}
]
```

Is this even possible to insert a new user status in this schema? Should I redesign the schema?
How to do it properly in BigQuery, to utilize its nesting abilities?

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and assumes you have a statuses table `project.dataset.statuses` as you described in your question and you have updates table `project.dataset.updates` where you accumulate updates for periodical updates of statuses table

So dummy data could look like

```
WITH `project.dataset.statuses` AS (
  SELECT 'a' user_id, [STRUCT<status_date DATE, value STRING>('2018-11-03', 'pending')] status UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', [STRUCT<status_date DATE, value STRING>('2018-11-04', 'pending')] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', [] 
), `project.dataset.updates` AS (
  SELECT 'a' user_id, [STRUCT<status_date DATE, value STRING>('2018-11-05', 'sent')] new_statuses UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', [STRUCT<status_date DATE, value STRING>('2018-11-05', 'pending')]
)
```

where updates table has exact same schema and represents new updates that needs to be added to main table

Below SELECT returns joined statuses

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  t.user_id, 
  IF(u.user_id IS NULL, status, ARRAY_CONCAT(status, new_statuses)) status
FROM `project.dataset.statuses` t
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.updates` u
ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```

You can use below DDL to "update" statuses table with them

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.statuses` AS
SELECT 
  t.user_id, 
  IF(u.user_id IS NULL, status, ARRAY_CONCAT(status, new_statuses)) status
FROM `project.dataset.statuses` t
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.updates` u
ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```

If to apply to dummy data

statuses:

```
Row user_id status.status_date  status.value     
1   a       2018-11-03          pending  
2   b       2018-11-04          pending  
3   c
```

updates:

```
Row user_id new_statuses.status_date    new_statuses.value   
1   a       2018-11-05          sent     
3   c       2018-11-05          pending
```

result will be as

```
Row user_id status.status_date  status.value     
1   a       2018-11-03          pending  
            2018-11-05          sent     
2   b       2018-11-04          pending  
3   c       2018-11-05          pending
```

In case if `updates` table can consists of new users that are not yet in main table - below will handle this scenario

```
#standardSQL
-- CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.statuses` AS
SELECT 
  IFNULL(t.user_id, u.user_id) user_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN t.user_id = u.user_id THEN ARRAY_CONCAT(status, new_statuses)
    WHEN t.user_id IS NULL THEN new_statuses
    WHEN u.user_id IS NULL THEN status
  END status
FROM `project.dataset.statuses` t
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.updates` u
ON t.user_id = u.user_id
```